# Printf ignoring null values?

Tags: c, null, embedded, printf, microchip

I am writing C code for an embedded target, Microchip PIC24, and the runtime libc for some reason won't properly send \0 values over the serial port.

```
printf("\xEE\xEE\0test");
```

for example sends EE EE "test", the null byte is ignored.

Has anyone a clue why this might be?

EDIT:  Ermmm, never mind XD. I was using puts to send over the string.. doh'

Comment: Does it send "EEEEtest" or just "test"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A null character is the string terminator in C.  `printf` stops there because the `\0` is the end of the string as far as it is concerned.  Use `putchar()`, or `printf()` with a format string may work:

```
printf("%c", '\0');
```

If you are getting `0xEE 0xEE test` on the line as you suggest, are you sure the `test` isn't coming from a different `printf` call?

Comment: Thanks, your comment made me aware of some stupid mistake.. I was passing sprintf through a puts, so while the former alone would work (\0 in the format string), the second puts stopped in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The null character signals the end of a string as far as printf is concerned.  I'm surprised it sends "test" at all. You're probably better off using the write system call especially over a serial port.

Comment: Use `write()` or `fwrite()`.  The difference is that `fwrite` does buffering and is defined by the C standard (though not required for freestanding implementations); `write` is defined by POSIX.  You might also need to ensure that the stream is in binary mode.  `stdout` is normally in text mode by default, though the details may be different for your embedded target.